# What does it mean by Everything is an object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, object

**What does it mean by Everything is an object in Kotlin?**

> In Kotlin, everything is an object in the sense that you can call member functions and properties on any variable. Some types can have a special internal representation – for example, numbers, characters and booleans can be represented as primitive values at runtime – but to the user they look like ordinary classes

Comment: It means exactly what it says in the quote. With what part(s) exactly are you having difficulty? Do you know what a variable is? Do you know what an object is in the OOP sense? Do you know what it means to call member functions on a variable?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: *In Kotlin, everything is an object in the sense that you can call member functions and properties on any variable.*

Comment: what it means to call member functions on a variable? can you show me an example please

Answer (score 7):

One of the very common criticisms of Java is that certain types, the *primitive types*, are treated specially. That is, there's a fundamental difference between `int` and `String` in Java. `int` is primitive and `String` is an object type. This has several downstream consequences.

- `int` is always passed by value, whereas `String` is passed by reference.
- `int` cannot be used in generics.
- `int` is non-nullable, whereas `String` can be `null`.
- You cannot call methods on `int`.
- `int` doesn't derive from `Object`, so even otherwise "universal" things like `toString` won't work on it.

So a Java programmer always has to be conscious of this and must treat these primitive types, in some sense, differently.

Kotlin eliminates this discrepancy. In Kotlin, `Int` is a class type just like `String`. It has methods, it's passed by reference, it can be nullable (`Int?` is well-defined in Kotlin), and it derives from the top type `Any`.

*Internally,* Kotlin is free to optimize this to a primitive `int` to make your code faster. But crucially that's an implementation detail. You as the programmer are free to just assume everything is an object, and Kotlin will work with you.